# My Ajax call does not submit to php

Tags: php, ajax

Following snippet should be collecting data and sending it to a php file.
It does output proper values on click of the button.

```
var dataString = 'username='+SessionVars.my_username+'&lessonid='+SessionVars.my_lesson_number;
$('#tracking_submit').click(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "php/tracking.php",
    type:'POST',
    data: dataString,
    success: function(){
    $('#tracking_message').replaceWith(SessionVars.my_username+"Thank you for updating."+SessionVars.my_lesson_number);
    }                   
    });
return false;   
});
```

Then the php file portion i'm using is this:

```
session_start(); 
mysql_connect("stuff i tested and it works");
mysql_select_db("same");

$username=$_POST['username'];
$lessonid=$_POST['lessonid'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO tracking ( username, lessonid ) VALUES ( ".$username.", ".$lessonid." );");
```

When I check the database, there is nothing in it.

Comment: Use something like the Google Chrome Javascript Inspector to see if you're getting any errors.

Comment: What you're doing is incredibly insecure.  You **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to use prepared queries with PDO to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: I totally agree with you Brad. At this point I am not worrying about security, I just want things to get from one side to the other, and then process the query strings to avoid sql injection.

Comment: yeah but u could at least at a little mysql_real_escape_string just to be safe and form a habit for basic security measures when using `mysql_*`

Comment: David, chrome does not show any javascript errors.

Comment: RPM, thanks for the tip, I'm actually using that on the other portions of site, I was just doing a hackjob to get the basic functionality down. fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot work, since you're not putting values in your query into quotes. This should help and prevent you being hacked as well:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tracking ( username, lessonid ) VALUES ( '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($lessonid)."' )");
```

Comment: Thank you, i used '$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$lessonid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lessonid']);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO wtf ( username, lessonid ) VALUES ( '".$username."', '".$lessonid."' );");'

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tracking ( username, lessonid ) VALUES ('".$username."', ".$lessonid." );");
```

You missed quotes in that line. Also, please read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: Thank you for your concern, I used basic mysql_real_escape_string when assigning the variables in the php file.

Answer (score 1):

change to..

```
$.ajax({
    url: "php/tracking.php",
    type:'POST',
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: {username: SessionVars.my_username, lessonid: SessionVars.my_lesson_number}, 
    success: function(){
    $('#tracking_message').replaceWith(SessionVars.my_username+"Thank you for updating."+SessionVars.my_lesson_number);
    }                   
    });
return false;   
});
```

do a print_r ($_POST) on the next page. Also yes, you should readup on some sql injection prevention.

Comment: What does "chache: false" do?

Comment: It means that a page with cache: false will always be re-requested rather than reusing a stored page in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the php file, which using the help of the guy's above was resolved through:

```
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$lessonid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lessonid']);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO wtf ( username, lessonid ) VALUES ( '".$username."', '".$lessonid."' );");
```